# PDF have too many items +100, Any Solution?

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, export, kartik-v

I hope they can help me with a problem I have when exporting many elements in a PDF file.

When you export it, the file is created and generated on a single sheet, and as there are 100 products or more the pdf file you see nothing. Can someone help me with this? Or has it happened before? Thanks everyone for your help.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'showPageSummary'=>false,
    'responsiveWrap'=>true,
    'condensed'=>true,
    'pjax'=>false, //Deshabilitado por doble pjax
    'striped'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'panel'=>['type'=>'primary', 'heading'=>'Recibos'],
    'toolbar'=>[
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}'
    ],
    'export' =>[
        'target'=>'_self',
        'fontAwesome' => true,
        'label' => 'Exportar',
        'dropdownOptions' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-default'
        ],
        // 'onInitSheet' => function (PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet, $grid) {
        //     $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray(['borders' => [ 'allborders' => ['style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN ]]]);

        //     },
    ],
    'exportConfig'=> [
        GridView::EXCEL=>[
            'filename' =>  $this->title,
            ],
        GridView::PDF=>[
            'filename' =>  $this->title,
            ],
        GridView::TEXT=>[
            'filename' =>  $this->title,
            ],
        GridView::HTML=>[
            'filename' =>  $this->title,
            ],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        // [
        //     'class'=>'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
        //     'width'=>'50px',
        //     'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        //         return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
        //     },
        //     'detail'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        //         // echo '<pre>';
        //         // print_r($model);
        //         // die;
        //         $searchModel= new ReciboDetalleSearch();              
        //         //$searchModel->id_recibo = $model->id;
        //         // $searchModel->id_recibo = 7;
        //         // echo '<pre>';
        //         // print_r($id);
        //         // die;
        //         $dataProvider= $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        //         // echo '<pre>';
        //         // print_r($dataProvider);
        //         // die;
        //         return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('/recibo-detalle/index', [
        //             'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        //             'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        //         ]);
        //     },
        //     'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'], 
        //     'expandOneOnly'=>true
        // ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'factura', 
            'value'=>'factura',
            'group'=>true, 
            'subGroupOf'=>1,   
            'label' => 'Recibo'

        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'id_cliente',
            'value'=>'id_cliente',
            'group'=>true,  
            'subGroupOf'=>1,   
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'id_ciudad',
            'value'=>'id_ciudad',
            'group'=>true,  
            'subGroupOf'=>1,
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'fecha',
            'value'=>'fecha',
            'group'=>true, 
            'subGroupOf'=>1,
            'filterType'=> GridView::FILTER_DATE,
            'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'autoclose'=>true,
                        'format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    ]
            ], 
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'r_eliminado',
            'value'=>'r_eliminado',
            'group'=>true, 
            'subGroupOf'=>1,
            'hiddenFromExport'=> true,
        ],
        //Detalle
        [
            'attribute'=>'id_producto',
            'value'=>'id_producto',
            'label'=>'Producto'
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'rd_eliminado',
            'value'=>'rd_eliminado',
            'hiddenFromExport'=> true,
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'gestionado', 
            'value'=>'gestionado',
            'width'=> '80px',
            'hiddenFromExport'=> true,
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header'=> 'Acciones',
            'headerOptions'=> ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
            'contentOptions'=> ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
            'template'=>'{delete} {view} {update} {gestionar}',
            'options' =>['width'=> '100px'],
            'hiddenFromExport'=> true,
            'buttons'=>[
                    'gestionar'=> function($url, $model)
                    {
                        return Html::a(
                            '<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-tasks "> </span>', 
                            $url,
                            [
                                'title'=>Yii::t('app','Gestionar'),
                                'class'=>'gestionargarantias',
                            ]
                        );

                    }
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            if ($action === 'gestionar') {
                    $url = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/gestion/create?id_recibo='.$model['id'].'&id_recibo_detalle='.$model['id_recibo_detalle'];


                return $url;
            }
            if ($action === 'view') {                    

                    $url = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/recibo/view?id='.$model['id'];


                return $url;
            }
            if ($action === 'update') {                    

                    $url = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/recibo/update?id='.$model['id'];


                return $url;
            }
            if ($action === 'delete') {                    

                    $url = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/recibo/delete?id='.$model['id'];

                return $url;
            }
          }
        ],
        // [
        //     'class' => '\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'
        // ]
    ],
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk0Vx.jpg

Comment: Apparently this is a grouping problem with PDF export and there is [issue](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/569) reported for this already but unfortunately it's almost one year old and still open. It should be ok when you remove grouping.

Comment: I will try. Thanks